# Django/PyCharm - Unresolved attribute reference '' for class 'User'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Just wondering if there's a way to get around this super annoying PyCharm warning without having to ignore it altogether.

I have a custom `User` model with extra fields and methods. When I try to access these attributes in a view (ex. `if self.request.user.type == 'foo':`) I'll get the warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'foo' for class 'User'` in the IDE.

It seems that PyCharm thinks that I'm still using `django.contrib.auth.User` even though I've specified `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'` in the project settings.

Comment: @monim my user model inherits from `AbstractUser` so the manager is `UserManager`

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this to avoid warnings. You can set the `type` of a variable say `my_user` to your `CustomUser` model and store the user from `self.request` in your views or elsewhere.

```
my_user: CustomUser = self.request.user

print(my_user.type) # Now pycharm won't shout :)
```